# Inquiring about the authenticity of Hayagrīva Upanishad

Tags: scripture, vishnu, vaishnavism, upanishads, sri-vaishnava

I came across one Hayagrīva Upanishad and researched about it. Many websites seem to offer its translation. (Like [this](https://sadagopan.org/ebook/pdf/Sri%20Hayagriva%20Upanishad.pdf) popular Sri Vaishnava site.)

I have never come across any quotation, reference, or commentary on this Upanishad by any great acharya, however.
My question is, can anyone find the earliest commentary on or quoting of this Upanishad? Can we date this Upanishad to ascertain its authenticity?

Comment: There is something about date on wiki: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hayagriva_Upanishad#:~:text=The%20composition%20date,the%2016th%20century Since it is a tantric in nature, it must be composed very late. I suppose sometime similar to Rama rahasya upanisat, say - after 10th century.

Comment: @AbhasKumarSinha I am trying to find an ancient commentary or quoting from it that would be very helpful in dating it